# Debian USB 3.0 PCIe Controller on LGA1366 mainboards error -108

Tags: usb, debian

Debian 64x - 5.4.0-0.bpo.4-amd64

CPU: Xeon 2xL5640

Mainboard: Tyan S7012 , Supermicro X8DTH-i - latest Firmware

I tested multiple USB 3.0 Controller with diffrent chipsets and latest firmware:

- Renesas D720201 (works best)
- Asmedia ASM1042A
- VLI805

The problem:

If i use the Asmedia / VLI controller they get correctly recognized by the OS. lspci:

```
04:00.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller
```

When i'm plugging in a usb-device (SSD) the device gets recognized and everything seems to be fine.

But as soon i transfering/reading data from the usb device i get follow I/O errors. dmesg:

```
[ 1017.102647] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 data in submit err -22 uas-tag 1 inflight: s-in a-cmd s-cmd work 
[ 1017.102649] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 16 4f bf 90 00 01 00 00
[ 1017.102670] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 data in submit err -22 uas-tag 1 inflight: s-in a-cmd s-cmd work 
[ 1017.102676] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 16 4f bf 90 00 01 00 00
[ 1017.102685] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 data in submit err -22 uas-tag 1 inflight: s-in a-cmd s-cmd work 
[ 1017.102689] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 16 4f bf 90 00 01 00 00
[ 1017.102697] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 data in submit err -22 uas-tag 1 inflight: s-in a-cmd s-cmd work 
[ 1017.102701] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 16 4f bf 90 00 01 00 00
[ 1017.102707] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 data in submit err -22 uas-tag 1 inflight: s-in a-cmd s-cmd work 
[ 1017.102710] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 16 4f bf 90 00 01 00 00
[ 1017.102717] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 data in submit err -22 uas-tag 1 inflight: s-in a-cmd s-cmd work 
[ 1017.102720] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 16 4f bf 90 00 01 00 00
[ 1017.102725] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 data in submit err -22 uas-tag 1 inflight: s-in a-cmd s-cmd work 
[ 1017.102726] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 16 4f bf 90 00 01 00 00
[ 1017.102731] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 data in submit err -22 uas-tag 1 inflight: s-in a-cmd s-cmd work 
[ 1017.102733] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 16 4f bf 90 00 01 00 00
[ 1017.102738] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 data in submit err -22 uas-tag 1 inflight: s-in a-cmd s-cmd work 
[ 1017.102739] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 16 4f bf 90 00 01 00 00
[ 1017.102747] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: s-in a-cmd s-cmd work 
[ 1017.102751] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 16 4f bf 90 00 01 00 00
[ 1017.102756] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#1 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD IN 
[ 1017.102758] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#1 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 16 4f be 90 00 01 00 00
[ 1017.142737] scsi host7: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[ 1017.686749] usb 6-1: device not accepting address 2, error -108
[ 1018.326748] usb 6-1: device not accepting address 2, error -108
[ 1018.966746] usb 6-1: device not accepting address 2, error -108
[ 1019.606750] usb 6-1: device not accepting address 2, error -108
[ 1019.662842] scsi host7: uas_eh_device_reset_handler FAILED err -19
[ 1019.662847] sd 7:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 1019.662850] sd 7:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 1019.662859] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#1 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
[ 1019.662862] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#1 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 16 4f be 90 00 01 00 00
[ 1019.662866] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 374324880 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 32 prio class 0
[ 1019.662891] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
[ 1019.662894] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 16 4f bf 90 00 01 00 00
[ 1019.662897] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 374325136 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 32 prio class 0
[ 1019.662906] sd 7:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 1019.662910] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 6296352 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 1019.662913] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd1, logical block 786788, lost async page write
[ 1019.662924] sd 7:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 1019.662928] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 378289224 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 1019.662930] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd1, logical block 47285897, lost async page write
[ 1019.662958] usb 6-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 1019.662969] sd 7:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 1019.662976] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 374324880 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 1019.662980] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd1, logical block 46790354, async page read
[ 1019.663282] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 374325392 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 32 prio class 0
[ 1019.663304] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 374325136 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 1019.663310] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd1, logical block 46790386, async page read
[ 1019.663383] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 374324880 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 1019.663386] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd1, logical block 46790354, async page read
[ 1019.664560] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 374324880 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 1019.664563] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd1, logical block 46790354, async page read
[ 1019.685740] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 1019.942746] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 1019.967255] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN Can't disable streams for endpoint 0x83, streams are being disabled already
[ 1019.967259] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN Can't disable streams for endpoint 0x81, streams are being disabled already
[ 1019.967800] usb usb6-port1: couldn't allocate usb_device
```

Those boards are EOL so i can't get a newer BIOS.
Both boards are using the ICH10R I/O hub.
I tested a lot of BIOS settings nothing seems to change anything.

The best results i got was with the renesas chipset.
At least i can read/write without any issue when i use a controller that has a renesas chip on it.

But the write speeds are relative slow (60-70MB/s on a USB3.0 when i'm using a SSD). Read speed is blazing fast around 300MB/s.

When i use this SSD on a other computer(windows) with USB3.1 i'm getting 300MB/s write speed.

Do you need more information, just let me know.
What is causing those issues ?
How can i solve them ?

Regards Int3g3r

dmesg (HDD-WD):

```
[  115.583156] usb 3-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  115.604468] usb 3-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=0704, bcdDevice= 1.05
[  115.604472] usb 3-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  115.604474] usb 3-1.4: Product: External HDD    
[  115.604476] usb 3-1.4: Manufacturer: Western Digital 
[  115.604478] usb 3-1.4: SerialNumber: 575843323038433838363831
[  115.626988] usb-storage 3-1.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  115.627352] usb-storage 3-1.4:1.0: Quirks match for vid 1058 pid 0704: 8000
[  115.627463] scsi host7: usb-storage 3-1.4:1.0
[  115.627631] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  115.631415] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  116.644046] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       2500BEV External 1.05 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[  116.644706] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  116.645027] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] 488397168 512-byte logical blocks: (250 GB/233 GiB)
[  116.645580] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[  116.645583] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 21 00 00 00
[  116.646307] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
[  116.646313] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  116.710075]  sdd: sdd1
[  116.713353] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
[  117.218517] DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2
[  117.218525] DMAR: [DMA Read] Request device [04:00.0] PASID ffffffff fault addr fffaa000 [fault reason 06] PTE Read access is not set
[  117.218723] DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 102
[  117.218728] DMAR: [DMA Read] Request device [04:00.0] PASID ffffffff fault addr fffaa000 [fault reason 06] PTE Read access is not set
[  117.218739] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARNING: Host System Error
[  148.110601] usb 3-1-port4: cannot reset (err = -22)
[  148.110607] usb 3-1-port4: cannot reset (err = -22)
[  148.110609] usb 3-1-port4: cannot reset (err = -22)
[  148.110610] usb 3-1-port4: cannot reset (err = -22)
[  148.110612] usb 3-1-port4: cannot reset (err = -22)
[  148.110614] usb 3-1-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  148.110617] usb 3-1-port4: cannot disable (err = -22)
[  148.110619] usb 3-1-port4: cannot reset (err = -22)
[  148.110621] usb 3-1-port4: cannot reset (err = -22)
[  148.110623] usb 3-1-port4: cannot reset (err = -22)
[  148.110625] usb 3-1-port4: cannot reset (err = -22)
[  148.110626] usb 3-1-port4: cannot reset (err = -22)
[  148.110627] usb 3-1-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  148.110629] usb 3-1-port4: cannot disable (err = -22)
[  148.110631] usb 3-1-port4: cannot reset (err = -22)
[  148.110633] usb 3-1-port4: cannot reset (err = -22)
[  148.110634] usb 3-1-port4: cannot reset (err = -22)
[  148.110636] usb 3-1-port4: cannot reset (err = -22)
[  148.110638] usb 3-1-port4: cannot reset (err = -22)
[  148.110639] usb 3-1-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  148.110640] usb 3-1-port4: cannot disable (err = -22)
[  148.110642] usb 3-1-port4: cannot reset (err = -22)
[  148.110644] usb 3-1-port4: cannot reset (err = -22)
[  148.110645] usb 3-1-port4: cannot reset (err = -22)
[  148.110647] usb 3-1-port4: cannot reset (err = -22)
[  148.110648] usb 3-1-port4: cannot reset (err = -22)
[  148.110649] usb 3-1-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  148.110651] usb 3-1-port4: cannot disable (err = -22)
[  148.110653] usb 3-1-port4: cannot disable (err = -22)
[  148.110688] hub 3-1:1.0: hub_ext_port_status failed (err = -22)
[  148.110737] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  148.110742] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 08 80 00 00 08 00
[  148.110746] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 2176 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  148.198586] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  148.198593] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 08 80 00 00 08 00
[  148.198597] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 2176 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  148.198604] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd1, logical block 16, async page read
[  148.204366] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  148.204372] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 20 00
[  148.204376] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 2048 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 3 prio class 0
[  148.290651] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  148.290658] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 08 00
[  148.290662] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 2048 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  148.290670] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd1, logical block 0, async page read
[  148.370618] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  148.370625] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 08 00
[  148.370629] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 2048 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  148.370636] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd1, logical block 0, async page read
[  148.371172] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  148.371176] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 20 00
[  148.371179] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 2048 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 3 prio class 0
[  148.450588] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  148.450595] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 08 00
[  148.450598] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 2048 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  148.450604] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd1, logical block 0, async page read
[  148.534658] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  148.534665] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 08 00
[  148.534669] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 2048 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  148.534676] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd1, logical block 0, async page read
[  148.539083] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  148.539087] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 20 00
[  148.539091] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 2048 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 3 prio class 0
[  148.626609] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  148.626616] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 08 00
[  148.626622] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 2048 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  148.626628] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd1, logical block 0, async page read
[  148.706661] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd1, logical block 0, async page read
[  148.786679] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd1, logical block 0, async page read
[  148.874686] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd1, logical block 0, async page read
[  201.549328] DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 200
[  201.549353] DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 220
[  291.597558] DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 200
[  297.442898] DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 200
```

dmesg (3) (ssd, intel_iommu=off)

```
 89.580210] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
[ 1233.114824] usb 13-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 1233.116501] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 1233.358779] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 1249.091526] usb 13-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 1249.116321] usb 13-2: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 1249.116325] usb 13-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 1249.116327] usb 13-2: Product: ASMT1051
[ 1249.116329] usb 13-2: Manufacturer: asmedia
[ 1249.116331] usb 13-2: SerialNumber: MI05MP12011900111
[ 1249.136707] scsi host7: uas
[ 1249.137333] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ASMT     2135             0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 1249.138091] scsi 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 1254.625586] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[ 1254.625729] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[ 1254.625732] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 1254.625981] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 1254.626764] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
[ 1254.658423]  sdd: sdd1 sdd2
[ 1254.660593] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
[ 1311.075954] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#20 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 7 inflight: CMD IN 
[ 1311.075961] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#20 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 5f 97 d8 00 00 10 00
[ 1311.076516] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#9 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 6 inflight: CMD OUT 
[ 1311.076520] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#9 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 10 f7 5c 00 00 04 00 00
[ 1316.183946] xhci_hcd 0000:08:00.0: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
[ 1316.183977] xhci_hcd 0000:08:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[ 1316.184034] usb 13-2: cmd cmplt err -108
[ 1316.184038] usb 13-2: cmd cmplt err -108
[ 1316.184041] usb 13-2: cmd cmplt err -108
[ 1316.184044] usb 13-2: cmd cmplt err -108
[ 1316.184047] usb 13-2: cmd cmplt err -108
[ 1316.184050] usb 13-2: cmd cmplt err -108
[ 1316.184053] xhci_hcd 0000:08:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
[ 1316.184092] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#8 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 5 inflight: CMD 
[ 1316.184098] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#8 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 10 f7 58 00 00 04 00 00
[ 1316.184102] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#7 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD 
[ 1316.184105] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#7 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 10 f7 4c 00 00 04 00 00
[ 1316.184109] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#6 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[ 1316.184111] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#6 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 10 f7 48 00 00 04 00 00
[ 1316.184115] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#5 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 4 inflight: CMD 
[ 1316.184117] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#5 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 10 f7 54 00 00 04 00 00
[ 1316.184121] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#4 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 3 inflight: CMD 
[ 1316.184123] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#4 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 10 f7 50 00 00 04 00 00
[ 1316.184134] usb 13-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 1316.215997] sd 7:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 1316.216001] sd 7:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 1316.216003] sd 7:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 1316.216004] sd 7:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 1316.216006] sd 7:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 1316.216007] sd 7:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 1316.216009] sd 7:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 1316.235976] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 6264792 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
[ 1316.235997] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 284646400 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 128 prio class 0
[ 1316.236001] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd2, logical block 35576704, lost async page write
[ 1316.236008] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd2, logical block 35576705, lost async page write
[ 1316.236011] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd2, logical block 35576706, lost async page write
[ 1316.236014] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd2, logical block 35576707, lost async page write
[ 1316.236017] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd2, logical block 35576708, lost async page write
[ 1316.236019] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd2, logical block 35576709, lost async page write
[ 1316.236022] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd2, logical block 35576710, lost async page write
[ 1316.236024] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd2, logical block 35576711, lost async page write
[ 1316.236027] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd2, logical block 35576712, lost async page write
[ 1316.236030] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd2, logical block 35576713, lost async page write
[ 1316.236137] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 284645376 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 128 prio class 0
[ 1316.236244] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 284642304 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 128 prio class 0
[ 1316.236346] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 284641280 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 128 prio class 0
[ 1316.236463] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 284644352 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 128 prio class 0
[ 1316.236573] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 284643328 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 128 prio class 0
[ 1316.236685] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 6264792 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 1316.236940] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 284647424 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 128 prio class 0
[ 1316.237156] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 32784 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 1316.811197] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 1317.051929] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 1317.104175] xhci_hcd 0000:08:00.0: WARN Can't disable streams for endpoint 0x81, streams are being disabled already
```

Comment: Does this issue happen with any other devices, or just your SSD (or mass storage devices generally)?

Comment: it does happen with any usb device

Comment: i added a dmesg from plugging in a HDD. I can save say that the usb cable is not defect and the hdd is working fine on a other machine.

Comment: Based on [this bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202723) and others linked there, have you tried booting with `intel_iommu=off`?

Comment: It seems like to work now. i did read and write 5GB of files without any issue. But write speed is still around 80MB/s , read 300MB/s  (SSD). Is the write speed not quite low ? Thank you!

Comment: Does the SSD perform faster on other systems? There are *plenty* of slow SSDs on the market.

Comment: Yes, the SSD does perform a lot better on a windows machine (300MB/s write speed).

Comment: Update: it's still not solved. I got again the same issues, see dmesg (3). iommu is off !